# replace inlineshapes using word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with many images in it and I wish to be able to select a file path (in which the new images are located and numbered i.e. 1 to 100) to then replace the existing images with the new images.

I have read a few posts of others retrieving the properties of existing inlineshapes to achieve this, but I have also read people succeeding with the following method which seems much simpler (I just haven't been able to get the code working fully yet). Currently the code will run and replace the last image perfectly fine, but then stops with error '438' - Object doesn't support this property or method when it tries to replace the second last image.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub Replace_images()
  Dim rg As Word.Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim doc As Word.Document
  Dim path As String

 'Ensure pictures are numbered with no leading zeros (in folder) & are .jpg
  path = "C:\filepathtopictures\"

   Set doc = ActiveDocument

For i = doc.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1

  Set rg = doc.InlineShapes(i).Range
  doc.InlineShapes(i).Delete
  rg = doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path & i & ".jpg", False, True, rg)

Next i

End Sub
```

I don't understand how the using the addpicture doesn't work for the next image when nothing has change from the last image. If someone could please explain why it doesn't work or tell me what needs to be changed that would be great!

Comment: If you drag the yellow arrow that Debug uses to indicate where the error occurs to `Next i` then press F5 again, to continue the macro (which would skip the problematical image) does it continue with no problem? If yes, then there's something "odd" about this image/InlineShape. Can you see how it differs from others, such as where it's located / what surrounds it?

Comment: I did as you said and the code seems to worked fine, I tested it on 4 images and all were replaced with the correct image, however I had to get the error then run script from next i each time. What could be the cause of this? As I thought it doesn't seem like there is any issue and yet it cannot cannot run fluidly.

Comment: Also the only other content in the document are captions underneath each image

Comment: The problem is almost certainly the target range (`rg`)... Put `rg.Select` just before the line of code to add the image. Click in the gray area to the left of that line of code (add a break point - you should get a red dot and the line should be highlighted red). Now when you run the macro execution will stop before executing the line add an image. The range should be selected. Look at the document and compare what is selected for this problem image and compare that to other selections.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to change anything. To clarify it isn't "a problem image", the last image of the document (first in the for - step) will be replaced effectively, however even though it works it seems as though the code reaches an error on the same line (as observed when I step through the lines and the add image line will add the image in the correct position, but at the same time bring up the error).

Comment: Hopefully the above makes it clear that my problem isn't a single image, but rather that only the first image in the for - step is replaced before the error occurs.What I was trying to say before is that if I run the code and receive the error then drag the yellow arrow to next i and run it will replace the next image and reach error. I can repeat this process and effectively change all images in the document. I just don't understand what the error is because it seems like the error occurs even though the add image line works...

Comment: I see it, now. It's this: `rg = doc.InlineShapes...` Why are you trying to set the new InlineShape to a Range object (and without the `Set` command, in addition)? Remove the `rg = ` and it should run OK.

Comment: That wasn't the issue the add picture line must be equal to something, but you make a good point that I was setting the new Inlineshape as a range, so to get it working I just set the add picture line to equal an Inlineshape object. Thanks for the help

Comment: The line doesn't need to be set to anything - just remove the parentheses around the arguments.

Comment: You are correct, it works either way, I guess setting the Inlineshape object is just an unnecessary step. Can you explain why adding parantheses requires an object to be set? When should I use parantheses and when shouldn't I?

Comment: If you use parentheses you need to assign the result to a variable of the correct data type. This is generally the case, not just with `Set`. So if you don't have `variable =` in front of it, no parentheses.